# Is it possible a $C^1$ function and a continuous but not $C^1$ function agree almost everywhere with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

for example, $y=|x|$ which is a continuous but not differentiable, is there continously differentiable function agreeing with it almost everywhere.

---

According to the hint in the comments, I think whether this statement is true:
if $f\in C^M$ and $g\in C^N$, if $M \neq N$. Can they still not agree almost everywhere.

Comment: Hint: suppose $f \in C^1$ and $g$ continuous but not $C^1$ have this property. Consider $h = f - g$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It seems h would be a continuous function and if there is a point at which h is not zero, then there is an interval around this point where h is not equal to zero. I have got the idea clearly thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. This is to do with the fact that continuous functions which are equal on a [dense set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) are equal everywhere. The complement of a set of measure $0$ is dense (since non-empty open sets have positive measure). Hence if two continuous functions are equal almost everywhere, then they are equal everywhere. Therefore, if a given continuous function $f$ has a particular property (e.g. is not differentiable), then every continuous function $g$ which is equal to $f$ almost everywhere must also have that property (since $f=g$).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have got the idea clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Re your second question, yes, a continuous and differentiable function may agree with a nowhere continuous ( and therefore not differentiable function): the function $f(x)=x$ and the Dirichlet function which takes the value $1$ on Rationals and $0$ on Irrationals is/are an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I come up with this simple question when I study the distribution theory. It is known that a locally integrable function could be identified with a distribution and this identification is achieved by agreement a.e.. But if a function is $C^1$, can we say a distribution is a $C^1$, since a distribution may represent a function differing from this function in a measure zero set. But it seems from the anwers, the answer is yes!